# How to control built-in Tabs change in New Message Window Outlook 2013

Tags: c#, outlook, add-in

I have an Outlook add-in 2013 that in case of a too big file attachment (bigger then Outlook supports), a notification window will show the user that he can use a ribbon button to attach those files. The problem is that if the user changes the Selected Tab in NewMailMessage window (from Message to Insert for example), the notification window won't be in the right place. So, I need somehow to change from code the Selected Tab and set it to the "Message" tab. Until now I couldn't find a solution to control the selected tab. Do you have any ideas about this?!

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "the notification window won't be in the right place"? Please show how exactly you show the window.

Comment: The notification window is my cusyom window that informs the user to use the ribbon button. But the ribbon button is on the "Message" tab, not on the "Insert" tab and the window is not pointing to the right button.

Comment: *is my custom window

Comment: I still do not understand what you mean - what is the "right" position of the window? Are you not responsible for explicitly setting the window position if you want anything other than the default position?

Comment: The window is not the main thing here, it's just a detail. Like I said, I need to be able to change the tabs of the New Mail Message Window (from Insert for example to Message) from code. That's it, forget about my custom window :-)

Comment: In Outlook 2013, you can use IRibbonUI.ActivateTab method. In older version of Outlook, you can use Redemption and its SafeRibbon.ActiveTab property (http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/SafeRibbon.htm) - it will work for all application, not just addins.

Answer (score 0):

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/7c8eb8dd-acff-40b8-b9b6-bd889228ffd7/how-to-control-builtin-tabs-change-in-new-message-window-outlook-2013?forum=outlookdev#d64db001-04fa-44f4-a799-b7fcb3abb294

ribbon.ActivateTabMso fixed it!

Comment: Ok, sorry for that! This link provides the full answer. Someone above copy and paste the answer as I can see now.